# How can I centre everything in a Bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have run into a problem when trying to code my semester project.
I'm trying to center all of this content right in the middle of the bootstrap card but It just can't seem to work:(

If someone can help me I would be really grateful!

[image]

Also if I can the card height taller.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card mt-5 container p-5 card-w ">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="card-img" alt="apples">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title h1 pl-5 mx-2 d-flex">Apple, Empire</h5>
        <p class="card-text pl-5 mx-2 lead font-weight-bold d-flex">1.94$/kg</p>
        <div class="container d-flex alignmentcard">
          <div class="d-flex mx-3">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">-</a>
            <p class="pt-2 lead">1</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">+</a>
            <button class="buttonshad buttonstyling bg-primary text-light mx-5">Add to cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container pt-4">
          <p>
            <a class="mx-5" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                          More details
                        </a>
          </p>
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quos ullam, earum commodi autem fuga, aliquam maiores dolorem libero inventore, molestiae omnis nam ipsam error consequatur ut nisi eveniet dolorum!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Two options: [Text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment) or [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content). What have you tried?

Comment: I tried text alignment but it only centers the text, when I try the flex utilities I get confused when there's many component to centre:(

Comment: Well, it's not entirely clear what you want since you have different layouts for mobile and larger screens. Please revise with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping every piece of your div from the beggining to the end with a `<center></center>` tag. After that, you would have something like this:

```
<center>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card mt-5 container p-5 card-w ">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="card-img" alt="apples">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title h1 pl-5 mx-2 d-flex">Apple, Empire</h5>
        <p class="card-text pl-5 mx-2 lead font-weight-bold d-flex">1.94$/kg</p>
        <div class="container d-flex alignmentcard">
          <div class="d-flex mx-3">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">-</a>
            <p class="pt-2 lead">1</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">+</a>
            <button class="buttonshad buttonstyling bg-primary text-light mx-5">Add to cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container pt-4">
          <p>
            <a class="mx-5" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                          More details
                        </a>
          </p>
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quos ullam, earum commodi autem fuga, aliquam maiores dolorem libero inventore, molestiae omnis nam ipsam error consequatur ut nisi eveniet dolorum!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```